# Finding The Zeros Of $(e^z-1) \sin z \cos z$

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

$$(e^z-1) \sin z \cos z$$

$(e^z-1): z=2\pi i k$ a zero of order $1$

$(\sin z):z=\pi k$ a zero of order $1$

$(\cos z):z=\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi k$ a zero of order $1$

Are those all the zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got all the zeros, but you missed the fact that $0$ is a zero of order $2$.

Comment: I need to derive twice and plug $z=0$ and see that $f''(0)\neq 0$?

Comment: It is enough to note that $0$ is a simple zero of $e^z-1$ and of \sin$.

Comment: So we can "sum" the orders?

Comment: @newhere Indeed. Why the quotation marks?

Comment: As I was not sure

Answer (score 0):

This is just an observation:

$$(e^z-1)\sin z\cos z=\frac{1}{2}(e^z-1)\sin 2z$$

So, $z=\frac{k\pi}{2}$ is a zero of order $1$ $\forall k(\ne0)\in\mathbb{Z}$ and if $k=0$ i.e $z=0$ then it is a zero of order $2$ and $z=2k\pi i$ is a zero of order 1 $\forall k(\ne 0)\in \mathbb{Z}$.